# Futur simple/conditionnel/présent

Tags: conditionnel, futur-simple

Je me demande comment il faut tourner les phrases suivantes afin qu'elles soient correctes :

> J'espère qu'il y aura un musée où je pourrais/pourrai/peux me promener en profitant des beaux tableaux.

> J'espère également qu'il y aura des librairies où je pourrais/pourrai/peux trouver des beaux livres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> J'espère qu'il y aura un musée où je pourrai me promener en profitant des beaux tableaux.

> J'espère également qu'il y aura des librairies où je pourrai trouver des beaux livres.

---

> J'avais espéré qu'il y [ait/aurait] un musée où j'aurais pu me promener

> J'espère qu'il y a un musée où on peut se promener

> J'espère qu'il y a un musée où je pourrais me promener.

> J'espère qu'il y a un musée où je pourrai me promener.

Comment: En ce qui concerne la 3ème phrase, je me demande si le conditionnel conviendrait mieux ici, car il s'agit du verbe "espérer" _J'avais espéré qu'il y **aurait** un musée où j'aurais pu me promener_. En tout cas, je vois plutôt des exemples avec le conditionnel sur _Google_.

Comment: @Oreste Oui, il y a bien plus d'**aurait**, ça ne fait pas de doute. J'ai hésité sur cette phrase. J'ai failli mettre : ***J'avais espéré qu'il y eut eu un musée où j'eusse pu me promener***.  ;-)

Comment: Je ne comprends pas vraiment la 3ème phrase. _J'avais espéré_, donc je ne l'espère plus, pour une raison ou une autre. OK. _j'aurais pu me promener_ Disons que j'habite trop loin à présent. Mais pourquoi tu emploies le subjonctif après _j'avais espéré_ ? Car il s'agit d'un évènement impossible ? Voici ce que j'ai trouvé [lien](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_e&page=92KNqkjd13RU.html) _L’emploi du subjonctif n’est pas exclu, et il est facilement toléré après l’impératif espérons ou on pourrait espérer_

Comment: _J'ai failli mettre..._ Pauvres apprenants. :)